# Can't run ubuntu after the reboot

Tags: installation, reboot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [cannot boot ubuntu after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/210571/cannot-boot-ubuntu-after-reboot)

I followed the installation instructions.
After the step of the reboot, when I try run ubuntu,
I get the message that the file is missing or corrupted.

Comment: Were there any errors when you installed Ubuntu? What version did you install? What kind of computer? Please try to give more details. This makes it easier to help.